# Tensorflow text classification with subject for each text

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, text-classification

I want to classify texts with additional input 'text' subject. I acquire these subjects from wikidata 'instance of' properties. I designed a neural net model as below. Network takes texts and subjects as input. Texts are encoded into vectors and than these vectors get pooled. Other input 'subjects', are taken as integers. These are then encoded with Category encoding(one-hot) and result of this is concatenated with result of text processing flow. Is this model okay for such a classification task? I'm not sure if one-hot encoding of subjects makes sense or not.

Code:

```
MAX_TOKENS_NUM = 5000  # Maximum vocab size.
MAX_SEQUENCE_LEN = 40  # Sequence length to pad the outputs to.
EMBEDDING_DIMS = 100

text_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
subject_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32)

text_layer = vectorize_layer(text_input)
text_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(MAX_TOKENS_NUM + 1, EMBEDDING_DIMS)(text_layer)
text_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(text_layer)

subject_layer = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(
    num_tokens=len(subjects), output_mode='one_hot', sparse=False
)(subject_input)

concatenated = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([text_layer, subject_layer])

output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(labels))(concatenated)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[text_input, subject_input], outputs=output)

model.summary()
model.compile(loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy())
```

Model Plot:

[image]

Comment: I think there is a higher chance that you get the answer on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to achieve—what is the ground truth that you're getting you supervision off of—but it's worrying me a bit that in `concatenate_9` you concatenate logits on the left with probabilities adding up to 1 from `category_encoding_11` on the right. A single dense layer is probably not "smart enough” to figure it out. But generally, my stance has always been, if it works good enough, it works.

Comment: I want to make use of subject of each entity to get better results. What can I do before concatenating category_encoding_11 then? @kkm

Comment: By the way sum of output of GlobalAveragePooling is not 1. It's not a softmax function. It's a bunch of values ranging from 0 to 1. Category Encoding on the other hand outputs one-hot encoding.

Comment: Oh, sorry for confusing you. Anyhow, I think the best SO to ask is CrossValidated. (DataScience is less mature yet, but that's IMO.) I do not grok what are the `y_true` for the loss in your task, and what is the issue with the model in general. No convergence? Throw another Dense layer maybe. :) “I'm not sure if one-hot encoding of subjects makes sense or not:” the generic answer is yes if there is enough training data and little relation between these “subjects,” i.e. no stuff like "king–man+woman≈queen” hiding there. Embedding should uncover it. I don't “feel” what the data is to answer.

Comment: If you have a text (in_41) and a set of subjects _for that text_ (in_42), maybe concat them and run through embedding together?

Comment: I tried using embedding layer after 'CategoryEncoding', but the resulting embeddings are not expressing the right value for the encoding. In the end, By concatenating just encodings and word vectors, I obtained about 10% improvement on the accuracy score. I think it works this way.

Comment: As the subject is also a text, you can use the same embedding layer for the subject input. Please refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#models_with_multiple_inputs_and_outputs) for the same example which might help you to build the required model.